# Регулярное выражение (...|...) с приоритетом

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Всем привет,

Есть 2 строки

- string1.**375.519**.png
- string2.**tablet**.png

Нужно составить регулярное выражение, которое будет находить часть строк, которая выделена (375.519, tablet)

То есть строка, в которой содержится 2 числа (могут быть только числа) через точку или слово (но это так же может быть число или слово, содержащее тире)

Мой набросок `.+\.([\d]+\.[\d]+|[\w-]+)\..+`

Этот regex находит tablet, но вместо 375.519 он находит 519, потому что это подпадает под 2ую часть выражения **[\w-]+**

Собственно вопрос. Можно ли как-то задать поредение группы (...|...) так, чтобы если есть то, что соответствует 1ой части, находилось, иначе производился поиск по 2ой части

P.S. если производить поиск по `([\d]+\.[\d]+|[\w-]+)`, то 2 части отлично находятся. Быть может проблема с .+. в начале

Comment: нужно найти то что после первой точки и до второй? или это не обязательно так?

Comment: мне кажется от  первой до последней

Comment: @Shiki ну да, я был не внимателен

Comment: @StrangerintheQ нужно взять либо 2 числа через точку с конца без расширения, либо 1 "слово" с конца без расширения

Comment: @Valentynanzhurov залогируйте весь match, возможно элементы извлекаются в разные элементы массива и вы берете только 1 из них

Comment: может так https://regex101.com/r/3RKFX6/2 ?

Comment: Примерные строки чаще всего не имеют смысла, потому, что потом может возникнуть другой вопрос. Что если будет такая строка `string.....3343.434....3434,png` Что тогда? Вы уверены, что правильно задаете вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регулярное выражение:

```
/^\w+\.((\w+)|(\d+\.\d+))\.png$/
```

Вариант для `js`:

```js
let string = 'string2.tablet.png';
let matches = string.match(/^\w+\.([\w\.]+)\.png$/);
console.log(matches[1]);
```

> **Doox911**: Удалил лишнее объявление переменной `let`. Вылетала ошибка.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то вот решение

```
^(\d+\.\d+)|((?!\.)^[\w+]*)
```

Пример кода на JS:

```js
const regex = /^(\d+\.\d+)|((?!\.)^[\w+]*)/gm;
const str = `375.519.png
tablet.png`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Есть вариант воспользоваться такой регуляркой ([\d]+.[\d]+|[\w-]+) и брать предпоследнее значение

```js
const a = /([\d]+\.[\d]+|[\w-]+)/g
const b = 'string1.375.519.png\rstring2.tablet.png'

const matchValues = [];

for (const el of b.split('\r')){
    const matchParts = el.match(a)
    if (matchParts.length > 1) {
        matchValues.push(matchParts[matchParts.length-2])
    }
}

console.log(matchValues)
```